# Matrix multiplication in tibble

Tags: r, dplyr, purrr

I have a specific question about how to do matrix multiplication in a tibble.

The sample codes are:

suppose I havea tibble `W` with dimension: `100-by-10`:

```
W <- as_tibble( x=matrix( rnorm(1000,0,2) ,nrow=100,ncol=10,dimnames = list(NULL,c("C1","C2","C3","C4","C5","C6","C7","C8","C9","C10" ) )))
```

and a known matrix `R` with `dim(R) = 5 ,11`.

I want to extract a `100-by-5` matrix from `W` and pre-multiply

```
R <- matrix(runif(55, 1,20), nrow = 5, ncol=11)
```

and

```
W_use <- as.matrix(W %>% select(C2,C4,C6,C8,C10))
```

Their product is

```
WR <- W_use %*% R
```

Since `dim(WR)=(100,11)`, I can put it in the original tibble `W` by

```
W_total <- W %>% add_column(WR)
```

My concern is that though I can achieve this by a tedious process, it's proved to be slow, particularly the matrix multiplication.

Can we use some smart ways to circumvent the matrix construction and multiplication and get the same tibble `W_total`? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If we need to do this in a single chain

```
library(dplyr)
library(magrittr)
W1 <- W %>% 
      select(C2, C4, C6, C8, C10) %>%
      as.matrix %>%
      multiply_by_matrix(R) %>%
      as_tibble %>%
      bind_cols(W, .)
```

---

Or use `crossprod`

```
W %>% 
   select(C2, C4, C6, C8, C10) %>% 
   t %>% 
   crossprod(R) %>% 
   add_column(.)
```

Comment: It's helpful! The only problem is that ```multiply_by_matrix``` creates just ONE column in ```W1```. So I also added several lines to fix it.

Comment: @tobinz If you look at the code, I used `bind_cols` there instead of `add_column`

Comment: Thanks! I tried the codes. It indeed returns a ```100-by-11``` tibble, rather than ```100-by-21```. I just figured out an alternative way to fix it: before ```bind_cols(W,.)```, adding  one line ```as_tibble %>%``` resolves this.

Comment: @tobinz sorry, I overlooked that part

Comment: @tobinz What would be your expected solution given that this works